# Flex Combobox closes automatically

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, air, flex3

I needed to make some changes to an air application that I made 2 years ago. The thing is: it is still written in flex3 and compiled to AIR 1.5. I didn't have the original project in flashbuilder, so I imported the source code in a new project.

I have tried to compile with flex 4 with backward compatibility, but that didn't work for me. So i deceided to compile with flex 3.5. Everything seems to work, except for the comboboxes.

When I click on a combobox, the dropdown opens but closes immediately. I have searched on this problem, but I cannot find a solution. It is just a standard combobox with 1 dataprovider. So no data is changed.

Does anyone know about this bug? How can I find out the compiler settings from an old AIR file. Maybe I can try to compile with the original SDK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding a second item to the data provider? Could be some odd logic in Flex that is closing it because there is nothing to select from.

Comment: There are multiple items in the data provider. In some cases 5, in some cases between 50 and 100.

Comment: combo box close usually when they loose focus. I would look into a focus change event

Comment: Problem is currently solved: I tried all the different SDK's from 3.0 untill 3.3. This 3.3 SDK solved the problem. Looks like i'm not going to be able to use newer functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you must have put `editable="true"`. I had the same issue and solved it.